# LG TROMM washing machine says door is open but it is closed

Tags: washing-machine

I suspect it is some kind of mechanical or electric connection that is not working but am at a loss on how to find out how to fix it.  It is a few years old but works fine.

I sometimes get it to work by opening or closing it or pushing on the door.

the door shuts tightly even when the error code says it is open.

EDIT
The problem is intermittent.

TROMM Steam washer
Model number:
Wm2688HWM

Comment: So, when you close the door, the machine acts as if you haven't closed the door? There's almost certainly a problem with the door sensor switch. Do you have the model number?

Comment: yes, the machine thinks the door is open

Comment: Can you post the model number?

Comment: @DanielGriscom  edited with model number

Answer (score 2):

According to this parts page: http://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/wm2688hwm/3204/0153200.html

you probably need a new washer door lock switch: http://www.searspartsdirect.com/lg-washer-parts/6601ER1004C/0026/795/model-WM2688HWM/3204/0153200.html

Part number 6601ER1004C; it's available from Amazon, both quickly (and more expensive) and cheaper (and more slowly).

To confirm, see if you can figure out how the door latches closed, and where the switch is, and then try operating it by hand.